# Uploading a video to facebook from an android phone

Tags: android, facebook

Anyone knows how to do that. Unlike youtube, there is no SEND intent coming form the the facebook android app.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is uploading videos from an SD Card to Facebook possible with the Facebook SDK?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908413/is-uploading-videos-from-an-sd-card-to-facebook-possible-with-the-facebook-sdk)

Answer (score 2):

### [Facebook-Android-Sdk](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk)

Instead of relying on an intent from 3rd party app (requiring users of your app to have the facebook app) you might want to **use a library** that hooks into **the Facebook API**- specifically the [facebook-android-sdk](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk). Facebook-android-sdk is maintained by Facebook and intended provide Facebook integration for Android Apps.

The library looks as if it provides support for uploading media/posting to walls, and so it should be able to do what you want.

You will need to [register for a Facebook App API Key](http://www.joomlabyte.com/how-to-get-facebook-api-key.html) on the [Facebook Developers Page](http://www.facebook.com/developers/).