# Share video on Facebook through my Android app

Tags: android, facebook, video

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is uploading videos from an SD Card to Facebook possible with the Facebook SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908413/is-uploading-videos-from-an-sd-card-to-facebook-possible-with-the-facebook-sdk)

I want to share a video on Facebook though my Android app.

I posted a wall though my application, and it's working fine. Now I am trying to share a video on Facebook. So I tried below code.

```
    Facebook facebook;

    String FB_APP_ID=APP_ID;

    byte[] data = null;
    Uri uri=Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"filename.mp4"));
    String dataPath = uri.getPath();
    String dataMsg = "Testing video sharing from my app";
    Bundle param;

    facebook = new Facebook(FB_APP_ID);
    AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);
    InputStream is = null;
    try {
        is = new FileInputStream(dataPath);
        data = readBytes(is);
        param = new Bundle();
        param.putString("message", dataMsg);
        param.putByteArray("video", data);
        mAsyncRunner.request("me/videos", param, "POST", new SampleUploadListener(), null);
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The reading bytes method is

```
public byte[] readBytes(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    // this dynamically extends to take the bytes you read
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    // this is storage overwritten on each iteration with bytes
    int bufferSize = 1024;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

    // we need to know how may bytes were read to write them to the byteBuffer
    int len = 0;
    while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        byteBuffer.write(buffer, 0, len);
    }

    // and then we can return your byte array.
    return byteBuffer.toByteArray();
}
```

The SampleUploader class is

```
public class SampleUploadListener extends BaseRequestListener {

    public void onComplete(final String response, final Object state) {
        try {
            // process the response here: (executed in background thread)
            Log.d("Facebook-Example", "Response: " + response.toString());
            JSONObject json = Util.parseJson(response);
            final String src = json.getString("src");

            // then post the processed result back to the UI thread
            // if we do not do this, an runtime exception will be generated
            // e.g. "CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original
            // thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views."
            Example1.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    mText.setText("Hello there, video has been uploaded at \n" + src);
                }
            });
        }
        catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.w("Facebook-Example", "JSON Error in response");
        }
        catch (FacebookError e) {
            Log.w("Facebook-Example", "Facebook Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

It is not working, and in logcat it shows the below warnings.

```
08-23 11:29:32.364: WARN/Bundle(860): Key message expected byte[] but value was a java.lang.String.  The default value <null> was returned.
08-23 11:29:32.374: WARN/Bundle(860): Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
08-23 11:29:32.374: WARN/Bundle(860): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String
08-23 11:29:32.374: WARN/Bundle(860):     at android.os.Bundle.getByteArray(Bundle.java:1305)
08-23 11:29:32.374: WARN/Bundle(860):     at com.stellent.Tout.facebook.Util.openUrl(Util.java:161)
08-23 11:29:32.374: WARN/Bundle(860):     at com.stellent.Tout.facebook.Facebook.request(Facebook.java:559)
08-23 11:29:32.374: WARN/Bundle(860):     at com.stellent.Tout.facebook.AsyncFacebookRunner$2.run(AsyncFacebookRunner.java:253)
08-23 11:29:32.386: WARN/Bundle(860): Key format expected byte[] but value was a java.lang.String.  The default value <null> was returned.
08-23 11:29:32.396: WARN/Bundle(860): Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
08-23 11:29:32.396: WARN/Bundle(860): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String
08-23 11:29:32.396: WARN/Bundle(860):     at android.os.Bundle.getByteArray(Bundle.java:1305)
08-23 11:29:32.396: WARN/Bundle(860):     at com.stellent.Tout.facebook.Util.openUrl(Util.java:161)
08-23 11:29:32.396: WARN/Bundle(860):     at com.stellent.Tout.facebook.Facebook.request(Facebook.java:559)
08-23 11:29:32.396: WARN/Bundle(860):     at com.stellent.Tout.facebook.AsyncFacebookRunner$2.run(AsyncFacebookRunner.java:253)
08-23 11:29:33.896: INFO/global(860): Default buffer size used in BufferedOutputStream constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k buffer is required.
08-23 11:29:33.905: WARN/Bundle(860): Key message expected byte[] but value was a java.lang.String.  The default value <null> was returned.
08-23 11:29:33.905: WARN/Bundle(860): Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
08-23 11:29:33.905: WARN/Bundle(860): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String
08-23 11:29:33.905: WARN/Bundle(860):     at android.os.Bundle.getByteArray(Bundle.java:1305)
08-23 11:29:33.905: WARN/Bundle(860):     at com.stellent.Tout.facebook.Util.encodePostBody(Util.java:63)
08-23 11:29:33.905: WARN/Bundle(860):     at com.stellent.Tout.facebook.Util.openUrl(Util.java:188)
08-23 11:29:33.905: WARN/Bundle(860):     at com.stellent.Tout.facebook.Facebook.request(Facebook.java:559)
08-23 11:29:33.905: WARN/Bundle(860):     at com.stellent.Tout.facebook.AsyncFacebookRunner$2.run(AsyncFacebookRunner.java:253)
08-23 11:29:33.915: WARN/Bundle(860): Key method expected byte[] but value was a java.lang.String.  The default value <null> was returned.
08-23 11:29:33.915: WARN/Bundle(860): Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
08-23 11:29:33.915: WARN/Bundle(860): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String
08-23 11:29:33.915: WARN/Bundle(860):     at android.os.Bundle.getByteArray(Bundle.java:1305)
08-23 11:29:33.915: WARN/Bundle(860):     at com.stellent.Tout.facebook.Util.encodePostBody(Util.java:63)
08-23 11:29:33.915: WARN/Bundle(860):     at com.stellent.Tout.facebook.Util.openUrl(Util.java:188)
08-23 11:29:33.915: WARN/Bundle(860):     at com.stellent.Tout.facebook.Facebook.request(Facebook.java:559)
08-23 11:29:33.915: WARN/Bundle(860):     at com.stellent.Tout.facebook.AsyncFacebookRunner$2.run(AsyncFacebookRunner.java:253)
08-23 11:29:33.935: WARN/Bundle(860): Key format expected byte[] but value was a java.lang.String.  The default value <null> was returned.
08-23 11:29:33.935: WARN/Bundle(860): Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
08-23 11:29:33.935: WARN/Bundle(860): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String
08-23 11:29:33.935: WARN/Bundle(860):     at android.os.Bundle.getByteArray(Bundle.java:1305)
08-23 11:29:33.935: WARN/Bundle(860):     at com.stellent.Tout.facebook.Util.encodePostBody(Util.java:63)
08-23 11:29:33.935: WARN/Bundle(860):     at com.stellent.Tout.facebook.Util.openUrl(Util.java:188)
08-23 11:29:33.935: WARN/Bundle(860):     at com.stellent.Tout.facebook.Facebook.request(Facebook.java:559)
08-23 11:29:33.935: WARN/Bundle(860):     at com.stellent.Tout.facebook.AsyncFacebookRunner$2.run(AsyncFacebookRunner.java:253)
```

How do I share a video on Facebook from my application?

Comment: could u arrange one working example of it. I surff so much for it. But not succeed to upload video....any demo example..Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I researched in Stack Overflow and found [an answer in *Is uploading videos from an SD Card to Facebook possible with the Facebook SDK?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908413/android-is-uploading-videos-from-sd-card-to-facebook-possible-with-facebook-sdk/6924732#comment-8626795).

Comment: I have try your code and it returns - oauthexception code 2500,OAuthException : An active access token must be used  can ypu please help me how to fix this error.