# Upload Video to Facebook Problems

Tags: android

I have gone through the post  [Upload to Facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7279510/upload-video-to-facebook) but where do i call the function of ***uploadvideo***.. 
I have also imported the facebook sdk and the sample project into workspace pls help me.
I have added the code into the AsyncFacebookRunner class should i have copied the code somewhere else.

This is my code that i have copied to AsyncFacebookRunner class

```
public  void uploadVideosFacebook(String videoPath) { 
            byte[] data = null;

    String dataMsg = "Video Desc.";
    String dataName="aaaassss.mp4";
    Bundle param;

    AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner = new   AsyncFacebookRunner(fb);
    InputStream is = null;
    try {
       is = new FileInputStream("/mnt/sdcard/aaaassss.mp4");
       data = readBytes(is); 

       param = new Bundle();
       param.putString("message", dataMsg);
       param.putString("filename", dataName);
       param.putByteArray("video", data);
       mAsyncRunner.request("me/videos", param, "POST", new fbRequestListener(), null);



    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
}



public byte[] readBytes(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
      // this dynamically extends to take the bytes you read
      ByteArrayOutputStream byteBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

      // this is storage overwritten on each iteration with bytes
      int bufferSize = 1024;
      byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

      // we need to know how may bytes were read to write them to the byteBuffer
      int len = 0;
      while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        byteBuffer.write(buffer, 0, len);
      }

      // and then we can return your byte array.
      return byteBuffer.toByteArray();
}


public class fbRequestListener implements RequestListener {

    @Override
    public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("RESPONSE",""+response);

    }

    @Override
    public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("RESPONSE",""+e);

    }

    @Override
    public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e,
            Object state) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("RESPONSE",""+e);

    }

    @Override
    public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e,
            Object state) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("RESPONSE",""+e);

    }

    }
```

and this is what i use when i call the onclick

```
public void onClick(View v) 
{
                  AsyncFacebookRunner.uploadVideosFacebook("/mnt/sdcard/aaaassss.mp4");
           }
```

My doubt is that 'm i calling the function correctly as once i run this i get an error saying the uploadVideosFacebook method should be converted to static i dont think this is right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow this answer instead: [Is uploading videos from an SD Card to Facebook possible with the Facebook SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908413/is-uploading-videos-from-an-sd-card-to-facebook-possible-with-the-facebook-sdk)

Basically you have to use AsyncFacebookRunner with the parameters **message, filename**, and **data**. Message is the short message to go with your video, filename is the type of file (ex: ".mp4"), and data is your video after converting into bytes.

Use AsyncFacebookRunner to POST this to "me/videos".

**Reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/video.upload/**

Comment: This is the whole post that i have used

Comment: Change your onClick to simply be: uploadVideosFacebook(String); You do not need the AsyncFacebookRunner.

Can you try sending a 3gp video instead? There may be a bug with mp4 videos on Facebook's end.

Comment: I'm calling the function in other class so i use it that way

Comment: Don't put uploadVideosFacebook() in the AsyncRunnerFacebook class. Put it in a import class you have or just in the Activity itself.