# Upload videos to Facebook from android application

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am developing an android application in that I want to upload videos to my and my friend's Facebook profile. I have seen Facebook android SDK but I am not able to work out from where to start? I don't know, how to authenticate user? Also I don't know how to upload videos? 
Can any one tell me which steps I need to take to upload video to Facebook? If possible also give sample code.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: just a simple search would do it... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908413/is-uploading-videos-from-an-sd-card-to-facebook-possible-with-the-facebook-sdk

Comment: I have already read this post and i tried to implement but i got errors so i thought i am missing some steps, that's why i have asked for steps. Please read my question properly.

Comment: You guys know how to post videos to... Facebook?

Comment: No I don't know that's why I have asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello everyone I have search on net and I found some help for my question. I have successfully implemented video uploading but some steps you need to take before you upload.

Please refer this [link](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/using-facebook-sdk-android-development-part-2) and implement the given case. It will allows you to do login and then use this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908413/is-uploading-videos-from-an-sd-card-to-facebook-possible-with-the-facebook-sdk) to implement video upload.

I have solved my problem but I have posted this answer just to help those people who face the similar problem.

Comment: have try with video from sdcard or from link except youtube video

Comment: thanks for sharing answer..  by referring this link i can only be able to upload 3gp video.. but i want to upload mp4 also... any help?

Comment: no I haven't tried that but if I get the solution then I'll post here. If you feel this answer is useful then please give +1 to answer as well as question.