# Out Of Memory Exception while uploading video to facebook in android

Tags: android

while uploading the video to facebook i am getting the Out Of memory exception log cat showing the following exception:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: (Heap Size=19783KB, Allocated=13705KB, BitmaSize=0KB) 
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.expand(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:91) 
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:216)
```

Please some one help me Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think when android heap size is more than 16 Mb,Its creates OutOfmemory Error.see this link.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908413/is-uploading-videos-from-an-sd-card-to-facebook-possible-with-the-facebook-sdk

Answer (score 0):

Sadly Android Dalvik VM imposes a limit on each process heap memory. It's arbitrary and depends on the implementation but it's usually 16 or 24 MB.

Profile your allocations and see how can you optimize them.