# How to upload large videos to Facebook wall with Facebook Android SDK?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

This answer does not work as expected because the sample code has to read the whole video file into RAM. On my Android 2.3 tablet with only 512MB RAM, it will trigger Out of Memory error.

[Is uploading videos from an SD Card to Facebook possible with the Facebook SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908413/is-uploading-videos-from-an-sd-card-to-facebook-possible-with-the-facebook-sdk)

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible for current Android facebook SDK! https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/ According to this web page https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/493/, the URL has to be graph-video.facebook.com, not graph.facebook.com. I have searched all Android facebook SDK java source codes, it does not connect to graph-video.facebook.com at all.

android-facebook-sdk sucks.