# Uploading mp4 Video to facebook using Android app

Tags: android, android-facebook

In my android app, the rquirement is to upload mp4 video files / JPEG images from SD card to facebook. We are able to post JPEG images to facebook. But when we try it for mp4 video file, it fails to upload. We are getting these errors

```
HTTP Error 400 Bad request
```

and error message

```
"error":{"message":"(#352) Sorry, the video file you selected is in a format that we don't support.","type":"OAuthException","code":352}}
```

Does it mean that uploading mp4 video files to facebook through Android is not possible at all ? Does facebook support uploading of mp4 files ?

Please help.

Comment: I had the same problem. Did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

A similar question has already been answered in StackOverflow.

[Is uploading videos from an SD Card to Facebook possible with the Facebook SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908413/is-uploading-videos-from-an-sd-card-to-facebook-possible-with-the-facebook-sdk)

Try **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908413/is-uploading-videos-from-an-sd-card-to-facebook-possible-with-the-facebook-sdk)** by [Erick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/703252/erick). The solution given there should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced your problem, and I changed the request params "video" -> "video.mp4" then it worked like a charm : ))

Here is my code

```
    File videoFile = new File(videoPath);
    AccessToken accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
    GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newPostRequest(accessToken, "me/videos", null, new GraphRequest.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
            Log.d("mylog", "uploadVideo Completed " + response.toString());
        }
    });

    Bundle params = request.getParameters();
    params.putString("access_token", accessToken.getToken());
    params.putByteArray("video.mp4", getFileInByte(videoFile));
    request.setParameters(params);
    request.executeAsync();
```