# How to upload (post) a video to Facebook using an Android app?

Tags: android, facebook, post, video, share

Trying to have a simple video upload app, found this answer which eclipse says many of the functions there are deprecated.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6924732/1525654

I'm using the latest Facebook SDK (version 3.16).

Is there a simple example for taking a video from the SD card and post it onto a Facebook's wall ?

Comment: Am I missing something ?
This is supposed to be quite easy I think

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did.
First your callback,

```
private Request.Callback requestCallback = new Request.Callback() {

        @Override
        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
            if(response.getError() == null) {
                Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, "Posted to Facebook.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, "Post to Facebook failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    };
```

Then, see if you have the publish_actions permission already,

```
private boolean isSubsetOf(Collection<String> subset, Collection<String> superset) {
        for(String string : subset) {
            if(!superset.contains(string)) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Then put this method inside your onClick() method

```
public void uploadVideoToFb(String caption) {
        // Get Facebook's active session.
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

        /*
         * Check published permissions first.
         */
        List<String> permissionList = session.getPermissions();
        if(!isSubsetOf(FacebookFragment.PERMISSIONS, permissionList)) {
            /*pendingPublishReauthorization = true;*/
            /*
             * Set additional permission requests to be able
             * to publish on the Facebook feed.
             * Inside PERMISSIONS is just "publish_actions".
             */
            Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionRequest = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(this, FacebookFragment.PERMISSIONS);
            session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionRequest);
            return;
        }

        new TaskDownloadAndPostToFb(this, caption).execute();

    }
```

Our publish_action permission,

```
public static final List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList("publish_actions");
```

Then here's my AsyncTask,

```
@Override
    public void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
        String baseDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + filename;
        File videoFile = new File(baseDir);
        if(videoFile.exists()) {
            Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
            if(session != null) {
                try {
                    Request request = Request.newUploadVideoRequest(session, videoFileLocal, requestCallback);
                    /*
                     * Take note of where to get the reference
                     of your bundle, it should always be
                     request.getParameters()
                     */
                    Bundle params = request.getParameters();
                    params.putString("description", this.caption);
                    request.setParameters(params);

                    request.executeAsync();

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "Video not found.");
        }

    }
```

Also, I have edited a lot of my code, of course, for security reasons. Let me know if something is lacking and broken.

I'm using [Facebook's latest SDK 3.17 as of August 7, 2014](https://developers.facebook.com/resources/facebook-android-sdk-3.17.1.zip)