# Android Facebook Video Upload Error Using Android API 4+

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I have this code, after logging in to Facebook, I want to upload selected video to Facebook through **Facebook Android SDK v4.13.1**,

## **Problem**:

The response looks OK to me, but the video is not showing in the Test User's Timeline.

## Code:

```
public void shareVideoFB(String videoPath, final ProgressDialog pd) {
    AccessToken accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
    GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newPostRequest(accessToken, "https://graph-video.facebook.com/me/videos", null, new GraphRequest.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
            try {
                if (pd.isShowing())
                    pd.dismiss();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            onFBShareVideoCompleted(response);
        }
    });
    Bundle params = request.getParameters();
    try {
        byte[] data = readBytes(videoPath);
        params.putByteArray("video.mp4", data);
        String albumName = "testFBUpload";
        params.putString("title", albumName);
        params.putString("description", " #SomeTag");
        request.setParameters(params);
        request.executeAsync();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

## **Response 1:**

```
 {Response: responseCode:200, graphObject:{"id":"10150481253673034", "url":"https:\/\/graph-video.facebook.com\/me\/videos"}, error:null}
```

## **Response 2:**

```
 {Response: responseCode:200, graphObject:null, error:{HTTPStatus:-1,errorCode:-1,errorType:null, errorMessage:"could not construct request body"}}
```

## **EDIT 1**

I have created a new test user with several permissions like

1. public_profile
2. user_friends,
3. email,
4. user_about_me,
5. user_actions.video,
6. user_likes,
7. user_videos,
8. publish_pages,
9. publish_actions

and upload the video but still getting the same response as **Response 1**.

## Edit 2

I just noticed that for test users the response is same as **Response 1** and with the exact Same ID ***10150481253673034***

Comment: when you get response1 and response2. Because response1 is ok but response2 return error

Comment: sometimes I get Response 1 and sometimes Response 2 is returned.

Comment: both response from same login user

Comment: 1 response is from Test User created from App Dashboard and 1 response is from my account that is added as a developer in the app dashboard.

Comment: @USKMobility Kindly see my edit.

Comment: @NadeemIqbal I hope your videoPath is correct.

Comment: @Drv Yes my videoPath is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Note:

My solution below is only working for Test Users. To post video from actual users **[refer this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/submission-process)** for submission process.

Although ***@Morales Batovski*** [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38249553/3884250) helped me but I want to answer my own Question as no answer was complete, I am posting a complete working solution:

## Create Test User:

Create a new test user with permissions (You may exclude some of un-necessary permissions):

1. `public_profile`
2. `user_friends`
3. `email`,
4. `user_about_me`,
5. `user_actions.video`,
6. `user_likes`,
7. `user_videos`,
8. `publish_pages`,
9. `publish_actions`

**You will add these permissions here (Screenshot)**

**[image: Screenshot]**

## build.gradle:

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
```

## MyAbstractFacebookActivity:

```
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.webkit.MimeTypeMap;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.facebook.AccessToken;
import com.facebook.AccessTokenTracker;
import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.GraphRequest;
import com.facebook.GraphResponse;
import com.facebook.Profile;
import com.facebook.ProfileTracker;
import com.facebook.login.LoginManager;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
import com.facebook.share.Sharer;

import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Arrays;

/**
 * Created by Nadeem Iqbal on 6/20/2016.
 */
public abstract class MyAbstractFacebookActivity extends MyAbstractActivity {

    private static String[] FB_BASIC_PERMISSIONS = new String[]{"public_profile", "email"};

    private CallbackManager callbackManager;
    private FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result> fbCallback;
    private AccessTokenTracker accessTokenTracker;
    private AccessToken accessToken;
    private ProfileTracker profileTracker;
    private Profile profile;
    private String fbId = "";

    byte[] data;

    private boolean LOG_FB_HASH = true;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        Log.e("FB HASH", getFBHashKey());
        fbInit();
    }


    public String getFBHashKey() {
        String key = "";
        try {
            PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                    getApplicationContext().getPackageName(),
                    PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
            for (android.content.pm.Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                key = Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT);
                if (LOG_FB_HASH) {
                    copyToClipBoard(key);
                }
                log("KeyHash FB:", key);
            }
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException | NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        }
        return key;
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    public void copyToClipBoard(String textToCopy) {
        int sdk_Version = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        if (sdk_Version < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            android.text.ClipboardManager clipboard = (android.text.ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
            clipboard.setText(textToCopy);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Copied to Clipboard!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            android.content.ClipboardManager clipboard = (android.content.ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
            android.content.ClipData clip = android.content.ClipData.newPlainText("Text Label", textToCopy);
            clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Copied to Clipboard!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    ///////// FB Work Start //////////

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        ///// FB Work Start //////
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        ///// FB Work End //////

    }


    void fbInit() {
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        fbCallback = new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Sharer.Result result) {
                log("Post Shared on FB");

                onPostSharedSuccessfully(result);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                toast("Cancelled");

                onPostSharedCancelled();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException e) {
                toast("Error:" + e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();

                onPostSharedError(e);
            }
        };

        profileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
            @Override
            protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile oldProfile, Profile currentProfile) {
                Profile.setCurrentProfile(currentProfile);
                profile = currentProfile;
            }
        };

        accessTokenTracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
            @Override
            protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(
                    AccessToken oldAccessToken,
                    AccessToken currentAccessToken) {
                // On AccessToken changes fetch the new profile which fires the event on
                // the ProfileTracker if the profile is different
                Profile.fetchProfileForCurrentAccessToken();
            }
        };

        // Ensure that our profile is up to date
        Profile.fetchProfileForCurrentAccessToken();

        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
                new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                        accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();

                        onFBLoginSuccessfully(loginResult, accessToken);
                        getNewFBId();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        warning("Cancel", "User cancelled the process");

                        onFBLoginCancelled();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                        warning("Error", "" + exception.getMessage());
                        onFBLoginError(exception);
                    }
                });
    }

    protected void getNewFBId() {
        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(
                            JSONObject object,
                            GraphResponse response) {
                        try {
                            fbId = object.getString("id");
                            onFbId(fbId);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });

        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("fields", "id");
        request.setParameters(parameters);
        request.executeAsync();
    }

    public abstract void onFbId(String fbId);

    public void doLogin() {
        doLogin(FB_BASIC_PERMISSIONS);
    }

    public void doLogin(String[] permissions) {
        try {
            LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithPublishPermissions(this, Arrays.asList(permissions));
    }

    ///////// FB Work End //////////

    public AccessToken getAccessToken() {
        return accessToken;
    }

    public ProfileTracker getProfileTracker() {
        return profileTracker;
    }

    public Profile getProfile() {
        return profile;
    }

    public String getFBId() {
        return fbId;
    }


    public static String getMimeType(String url) {
        String type = null;
        String extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(url);
        if (extension != null) {
            type = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
        }
        return type;
    }

    private static String getPrivacy(String privacy) {
        String str;
        if (privacy.equalsIgnoreCase("Everyone"))
            str = "EVERYONE";
        if (privacy.equalsIgnoreCase("Friends and Networks"))
            str = "NETWORKS_FRIENDS";
        else if (privacy.equalsIgnoreCase("Friends of Friends"))
            str = "FRIENDS_OF_FRIENDS";
        else if (privacy.equalsIgnoreCase("Friends Only"))
            str = "ALL_FRIENDS";
        else if (privacy.equalsIgnoreCase("Custom"))
            str = "CUSTOM";
        else if (privacy.equalsIgnoreCase("Specific People..."))
            str = "SOME_FRIENDS";
        else
            str = "SELF";

        return str;
    }

    public void shareVideoFB(String videoPath, final ProgressDialog pd) {
        AccessToken accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();

        Uri fileUri = Uri.parse(videoPath);
        String fileName = videoPath.substring(videoPath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, videoPath.length());
        String mimeType = getMimeType(videoPath);

        try {
            data = readBytes(videoPath);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        int videoSize = data.length;

        String privacy = getPrivacy("Friends Only");

        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newPostRequest(accessToken, "/me/videos", null, new GraphRequest.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                try {
                    if (pd.isShowing())
                        pd.dismiss();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }

                onFBShareVideoCompleted(response);
            }
        });

        Bundle params = request.getParameters();

        params = request.getParameters();
        params.putByteArray(fileName, data);

        params.putString("title", fileName);
        params.putString("description", "Some Description...");

//        params.putString("upload_phase", "start");
        params.putInt("file_size", data.length);

        request.setParameters(params);
        request.executeAsync();

    }


    public byte[] readBytes(String dataPath) throws IOException {
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(dataPath);
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        int len;
        while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            byteBuffer.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }

        return byteBuffer.toByteArray();
    }

    protected abstract void onFBShareVideoCompleted(GraphResponse response);    

    protected abstract void onFBLoginError(FacebookException exception);

    protected abstract void onFBLoginCancelled();

    protected abstract void onFBLoginSuccessfully(LoginResult loginResult, AccessToken accessToken);

    protected abstract void onPostSharedError(FacebookException e);

    protected abstract void onPostSharedCancelled();

    protected abstract void onPostSharedSuccessfully(Sharer.Result result);

}
```

## Share:

(This activity implements **MyAbstractFacebookActivity** and requires *string* **path** value from intent, My FB Share button listener is **onFacebookShareButtonClick()** )

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.facebook.AccessToken;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.GraphResponse;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
import com.facebook.share.Sharer;

public class Share extends MyAbstractFacebookActivity {

    String path = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_share);
        setHeader("Share");

        path = getIntent().getStringExtra("path");
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(path)) {
            toast("Path is null, Exiting Activity");
            finish();
        }
    }

    public void setHeader(String header_title) {
         // ... My Implementation
    }

    public void back(View v) {
        finish();
    }

    public void onFacebookShareButtonClick(View view) {
        // Facebook Share button Click Listener...
        String[] FB_BASIC_PERMISSIONS = new String[]{"publish_actions"};

        doLogin(FB_BASIC_PERMISSIONS);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFBLoginError(FacebookException exception) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onFBLoginCancelled() {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onFBLoginSuccessfully(LoginResult loginResult, AccessToken accessToken) {
//        getNewFBId();

        ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(this);

        pd.setMessage("Uploading Video, Please wait...");
        pd.setCancelable(false);
        pd.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        pd.show();

        shareVideoFB(path, pd);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostSharedError(FacebookException e) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostSharedCancelled() {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostSharedSuccessfully(Sharer.Result result) {

    }

    boolean isCalledEarlier = false;

    @Override
    public void onFbId(String fbId) {
        if (!isCalledEarlier) {
            ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(this);

            pd.setMessage("Uploading Video, Please wait...");
            pd.setCancelable(false);
            pd.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            pd.show();

            shareVideoFB(path, pd);

            isCalledEarlier = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFBShareVideoCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
        // Here the  video share response will come...
        toast(response.toString());
        log(response.toString());
    }

}
```

## Result:

[image: Test User Timeline]

Answer (score 3):

You got 2 responses.

Response 1 is from test user.i.e. video is shared successfully. -> So you need to login to facebook using test user's credentials provided from `Facebook developer console` and check in timeline. If you don't find it in timeline then check it out in profile. You will definitely find it out there.

> Sometimes it doest not shows shared post on timeline due to some privacy settings set in that account.

Response 2 is from another account. -> It is failed because unless Facebook approves your app, it will not allow you to share video using another account except test account.  So when you application will get approval of `publish_actions` from Facebook submission process then you can test using different accounts.
So it is okay for this case.

Refer https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/submission-process for submission process.

Comment: For test user, I have logged in from test user after sharing the video. But there was no video. Nothig in profile nor in timeline.

Comment: As status code is 200 and it is returning id and error is null, It indicates that your request is okay. You can refer http://stackoverflow.com/a/30446231/3817374

Comment: Your answer didnot helped me.

Comment: @ Nadeem Iqbal : Oh  so issue was in developer console in granting permission to new users?

Comment: Yes, the permissions was also the problem, but `/me/videos` and `file_size`parameter did the trick to me

Comment: Great. You posted the original issue. Will help others who are facing same. Will upvote your answer.. (y)

Comment: My answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38300231/3884250) is working for test users, For actual users `publish_actions` submission is required as per facebook guidelines.

Answer (score 2):

In the creation of *GraphRequest* replace graph path `https://graph-video.facebook.com/me/videos` by `/me/videos`.

```
GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newPostRequest(accessToken, "/me/videos", null, new GraphRequest.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
            // your code
        }
    });
```

## Source:

[Video Upload with Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/video-uploads)

[Graph API Reference: Video](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/video)

You can publish videos by using the following edges:

- `/{user-id}/videos`
- `/{event-id}/videos`
- `/{page-id}/videos`
- `/{group-id}/videos`

Comment: This worked :) Thanks. `/me/videos` and `file_size` parameter did the trick to me. I am posting the complete working solution

Comment: By the way, how did you come to know this?

Comment: From Facebook SDK documentation. Check my edit above.